# Not able to initiate mlx5 vf sriov

Tags: dpdk

I am using dpd19.11 and having error when trying to use sriov vf of a mlx5 100G card
Here is the error message i have

```
net_mlx5: Unexpected error in DR drop action support detection
```

The same code work for pf
The same code +/- compiled with dpdk17 work for vf
I am not trying to do filtering on nic, but just to read from the port, 1 rx queue, 1 tx queue

```
Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:0b:00.0 'MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5 Virtual Function] 1018' if=ens192 drv=mlx5_core unused=igb_uio
0000:13:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' if=ens224 drv=vmxnet3 unused=igb_uio *Active*
0000:1b:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' if=ens256 drv=vmxnet3 unused=igb_uio *Active*

ethtool -i ens192
driver: mlx5_core
version: 5.0-0
firmware-version: 16.29.1016 (HPE0000000009)
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:0b:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

Code example can be found at the following
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d38f87799c3365c
It happens even with 1 rx queue and no rte flow defined

From dpdk site, firmware version looks ok
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/rel_notes/release_19_11.html#tested-platforms